# macOS, Use fn + Command keyboard shortcuts work

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

Aside from switching between the playback/system control keys and the regular function keys, in macOS the <kbd>fn</kbd> key can be used to access keys not available on the keyboard. For example, if a dedicated <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd> key there isn't present, then <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd> result in <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>.

My problem is that this behaviour doesn't persist for keyboard shortcuts: when used in conjunction with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> or <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd> is ignored. This generates a few inconsistencies.

For example, on my 2017 MacBook Pro <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd> will all previous characters in the current line. Given that <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd> will delete the *next* character, I would expect <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd> to delete the *remaining* portion of the line. However, <kbd>fn</kbd> gets ignored and this key combination ends up deleting the previous portion of the line.

How can I have access to the "hidden keys" accessible with <kbd>fn</kbd> even when <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> is pressed?

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 4):

Even with both  <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd>  & <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> keys,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd>  does not clear the line forward of the cursor, even though  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd>   clears it rearward.

It would appear the inconsistency isn't in the  <kbd>Fn</kbd>   key itself, but in the OS's usage of  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> .

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd>  deletes one word forward of the cursor, as does  <kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd> .

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Then the problem is twofold: I still can't use fn to turn Backspace into Delete when the Command key is pressed (i've checked using the keyboard viewer), but even if I did, the keyboard shortcut wouldn't work.

Comment: It works here, according to the keyboard viewer [which I hadn't thought to test before, only the result in a file]

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean that you are able to delete the remaining portion of the line using Command + Delete or that you managed to use fn+Backspace as Delete even through you're pressing Command?

Comment: Fn/Backspece registers as Del. Forward line delete doesn't work with either method, only the opposite direction, as I said in my answer.

Comment: Ok, understood, then you're right: it's the keyboard shortcut itself that is missing from macOS.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that there are no 'hidden keys'. Just [documented built-in keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

- <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>: Forward delete on keyboards that don't have a Forward Delete   key. Or use Control-D.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>–<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>: Page Up: Scroll up one
  page.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>–<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>: Page Down: Scroll down one page.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>–<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>: Home: Scroll to the beginning of a document.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>–<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>: End: Scroll to the end of a document.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use the free software [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) to remap the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to a custom modifier.
You can then create shortcuts for <kbd>my_modifier_1</kbd>+<kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> etc.

The custom modifier would act as an additional modifier and thus stack with other modifiers.

You would have to manually rebind all the shortcuts that previously existed with <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

Here is an example of creating a customer modifier in Karabiner.

```json
[
    {
        "type": "basic",
        "from": {
            "key_code": "fn",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [],
                "optional": ["any"]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "set_variable": {
                    "name": "my_modifier_1",
                    "value": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "to_after_key_up": [
            {
                "set_variable": {
                    "name": "my_modifier_1",
                    "value": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have a magic keyboard with an <kbd>⏏</kbd> button. I've remapped it to the <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd> using the following Karabiner Simple modification:
[image]

It now works with all other modifier keys!

Comment: The issue doesn't appear to be a key remap problem, but one of a function that appears to have been omitted from the OS itself.

Comment: Exactly. This I could probably get this to work, it's probably too cumbersome and on a MacBook keyboard there aren't "spare" keys that I would turn into modifier keys. However thanks for introducing me to Karabiner

Answer (score 1):

Some <kbd>fn</kbd> key combos not in the [documented built-in keyboard shortcuts list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236):

- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> shows emoji picker
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> focuses keyboard on the Dock
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> opens app launcher
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> switches the current app to full screen mode
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> shows the desktop
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> shows the control center
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> shows notifications (sames as swiping left with two fingers from the right edge of the trackpad)
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> focuses keyboard in the menu bar

Not 100% sure whether these are defaults, or whether I have some setting (maybe in Accessibility) switched on that enables these shortcuts.